# Add zero before decimal place in SAS

Tags: sas

Hello I need to add a zero for only results and ranges are in a .2, .3 etc format but not tall values are like this. What would be the most efficient way to do this?.

I've only tried to format it using a w.d but the issue is that not all values are the same and all I want to do is add a zero for where they are applicable without messing the format of the other values.

format lborres lbornlo lbornhi z7.2.;

[image]

Comment: You need to provide significantly more details, specifically, what do you have and what do you want. Show us some examples. Per SO you should also include anything you've tried so far.

Comment: @reeza I can't display images but I've added more context

Comment: Type up a made up example if you need to, and identify what you have versus what you want.

Comment: Do you want the values to show as 0.5 rather .5? Is that what you're asking how to do?

Comment: I have typed the format statement I used and there should be an image of the data. I just want it to be 0.1 instead of  .1 etc.

Comment: What is the type of your variables that you want to change? Character or numeric? That's a screenshot from Excel, show it from SAS so we can see the types as well.

Comment: They're all character so realised that format statement isn't going to work. I updated the image for the sas dataset.

Comment: That's why I asked. You can convert it to numeric and then back to character using INPUT/PUT()

Comment: Would that not offset the rest of the formatting for the other variables which are not all numeric values?. Is there not just a way to code if ' '> 0 prior to the decimal place replace it with a zero? maybe using the TRANSWRD function?

Comment: Change only the variables needed. A variable has to be numeric or character and cannot have mixed types. If you have mixed types it must be character. If that's your situation you need some IF/THEN statements to isolate your logic for the numeric variables. You cannot do mathematical comparisons with character variables so > 0 may give you unexpected results, especially if you have mixed types.

Comment: Character values don't have a decimal place.  Character representation of a numeric value might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is numeric you can apply a standard format and that would add the leading zero.

ie

```
format yourVariable 8.1;
```

If your variable is character then you can test if the first character is a period and add a 0 or you can convert it to a number and store it that way instead. Option 2 is illustrated first as the first option overwrites the variable so to avoid any issues with that it's shown after.

```
data want;
   set yourInputDataSet;

   *Option 2;
   new_numeric_variable = input(yourVariable, 8.);
   format new_numeric_variable 8.1;

   *Option 1;
   if yourVariable =: '.' then yourVariable = catt('0', yourVariable);


run;
```

And as always, if your variable is incorrectly formatted this way, I would check my data import step and see if I can fix it there instead of after the fact. This is especially true if you used PROC IMPORT on a text file, where you can easily control the variable format and types as they're read in.

Comment: Run it and check, note the usage of the `=: `not just an equal sign.

Comment: This worked thank you so much for your help and that usage will be very helpful in the future

Answer (score 0):

Are you value all less than 1? eg.

```
.3
.002
.752
.056
```

If not you would have to create picture format for each unit (thousands, hundreds, tens etc)

If they are all less than 1,  z5.3 I believe will give you - 5 being the total length and 3 the number of decimal points.

```
data test;
  format A z5.3;
  a=.3; output;     /* 0.300 */
  a=.002; output;   /* 0.002 */
  a=.752; output;   /* 0.752 */
  a=.056; output;   /* 0.056 */
run;
```